# Uploading a CSV file to the web server and inserting the row's into the database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

At the moment I am able to get data from a CSV file called "data.csv" which I manually uploaded to the web server. I am able to then upload the data to database and this all works fine.

What I need to be able to do is:

1. Simply upload the file to the web server into the root directory
2. Regardless of what order the CSV files header's are in, for example, even if one user uploads a CSV file where the order of the columns are like so (name | email | address) but another user uploads a CSV file where the order of the columns are like so (email | address | name). So essentially I need to upload the appropriate data to the correct database field where the CSV header's name matches that of the field name within the table?

Code Below:

upload.php

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$file = "data.csv";
$separator = ",";
$length = 0; 
$fields = array('title', 'firstName', 'secondName', 'emailAddress', 'houseNumber', 'mobileNumber', 'address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'postcode'); 

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

$header = array_flip(fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator));

$values = array();

$i = 1;

while(($csvData = fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator)) !== false){

$values = array();

echo $i." - You have inserted another row of data into the database.<br>";

    foreach ($fields as $field){
        $values[] = $csvData[$header[$field]];
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (" . implode(',', array_keys($header)) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')"); 

$i++;

}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Please ask if I haven't quite explained this properply.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I addressed this that last time you asked this question. Your `implode(",", array_keys($header))` should be `implode(",", $fields);`

Comment: @Orangepill Aw I see, What I forgot to do earlier was remove array_keys(). Thanks very much.

Comment: How would I go about uploading a CSV file to the web server?

Comment: not a problem -- I would advise to to do the array_map with the call to mysql_real_escape_string to make sure unescaped characters don't cause your script to fail

Comment: @Orangepill I'll do that but how do I upload a CSV file to the server whilst always giving it the name of "data.csv"?

Comment: You wouldn't... check out [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for a primer on uploading files to php... you wouldn't assume the name to be data.csv you would get what the temporary file name that is assigned to it from php.

Comment: @Orangepill how would I do it assuming the the name is always "data.csv", I really need a hand here? The page you sent me to didn't help much at all.

Comment: You don't need to nor should you make the assumption that the file will always be name data.csv... see answer for a solution for you.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**warning**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

The Following should be a complete solution for you.

In your html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sompepage.php" method="POST">
<!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

In PHP (somepage.php)

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$separator = ",";
$length = 0; 
$fields = array('title', 'firstName', 'secondName', 'emailAddress', 'houseNumber', 'mobileNumber', 'address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'address4', 'postcode'); 

$handle = fopen($file, "r");

$header = array_flip(fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator));

$values = array();

$i = 1;

while(($csvData = fgetcsv($handle, $length, $separator)) !== false){

$values = array();

echo $i." - You have inserted another row of data into the database.<br>";

    foreach ($fields as $field){
        $values[] = $csvData[$header[$field]];
    }
    $values = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $values);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO csv (" . implode(',', $fields) . ") VALUES ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')"); 

$i++;

}

fclose($handle);

?>
```